# How to remove multiple indices from a ListBuffer (in a fast way)?

Tags: scala

Is there a nice way in Scala to delete multiple indices from a ListBuffer (in a fast way) ?

Example:

```
val indicesToDelete = List(4, 1)
val buffer = ListBuffer(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Result:

```
ListBuffer(b, c, e)
```

I could not find a pre-defined function that does the job.

One could sort the indices and remove the elements beginning with the highest index etc, so there will be no complication. But sorting requires `O(n * log n)`. Is there a faster way (maybe something pre-defined I missed) ?

**UPDATE 1:** The elements should be removed in the existing ListBuffer object, no new ListBuffer object should be created.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your description whether you want to create a new ListBuffer or mutate the existing one.  That's going to have a huge impact on the style of code that needs to be written.  Most of the answers written so far seem to have interpreted as "create a new one" but the concern about index renumbering in your description seems to imply in-place delete.

Comment: One can sort `indicesToDelete` in O(n) using [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

Comment: @JamesIry Yes, you are right, this point was not clear. Yes, I wanted to do the removing as an in-place deletion, not creating a new ListBuffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike others, I'm going to assume you want to do your work in-place because you mention a concern about index renumbering. If the sort is all you care about then

1) Stick the indices to be removed into a constant time lookup set instead of a list.  A hash set or bit set would seem appropriate depending on the range of indices.
2) Walk the list buffer in reverse order removing indices that are in the to-delete set.

```
scala> val buffer = ListBuffer("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
buffer: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[java.lang.String] = ListBuffer(a, b, c, d, e)

scala> val indicesToDelete = BitSet(4, 1)
indicesToDelete: scala.collection.mutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 4)

scala> for (i <- (buffer.size -1) to 0 by -1) if (indicesToDelete contains i) buffer remove i

scala> buffer
res19: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[java.lang.String] = ListBuffer(a, c, d)
```

Note that while this removes the n log n sort of indices, that doesn't make this a linear algorithm.  In-place delete from an array-like structure isn't cheap.  Higher indices have to be copied downward on each delete.

To get a linear delete of indices you need to do something much hairier, you need to 1) walk in the forward direction copying non-deleted elements downward based on the number that you've deleted so far. When you're done you 2) remove the top n elements where n is the number that you deleted.

```
scala> val buffer = ListBuffer("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")  
buffer: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[java.lang.String] = ListBuffer(a, b, c, d, e)

scala> val indicesToDelete = BitSet(4, 1)
indicesToDelete: scala.collection.mutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 4)

scala> var deleted = 0
deleted: Int = 0

scala> for (i <- 0 until buffer.size)
     |    if (indicesToDelete contains i) {
     |       deleted += 1
     |    } else if (deleted > 0) {
     |        buffer(i - deleted) = buffer(i)
     |    }

scala> }

scala> buffer trimEnd deleted

scala> buffer
res0: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[java.lang.String] = ListBuffer(a, c, d)
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. Yes, I wanted to remove the elements from the ListBuffer I am working with and not create a new one.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `zipWithIndex`, as the other posts already do, because otherwise the indices will shift and you could accidentally remove wrong items. But instead of `foldLeft` or `filter` + `map` I would use `collect`, what in this case does the same as `filter` + `map`, but in a single step.

```
buffer.zipWithIndex.collect { case (x,i) if !indicesToDelete.contains(i) => x }
```

this can also be written as

```
for {
  (x,i) <- buffer.zipWithIndex
  if !indicesToDelete.contains(i)
} yield x
```

Comment: Nice. I knew there'd be a more concise way than filter+map. Good old SO.

Comment: Depends on `indicesToDelete`. If it is a `List` it's O(MN), if it is a `Set` it is O(N log M).

Comment: @drexin: And O(N) amortized for a HashSet for appropriately small numbers of M.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
buffer.zipWithIndex.filter( p => !(indicesToDelete contains p._2) ).map( _._1 )
```

Which is `O(NM)` where `N` is the number in `buffer`, `M` the number of elements in `indicesToDelete`.

And if you're concerned about performance, you could always make `indicesToDelete` a `Set`. In which case the performance is `O(N`): assuming `O(1)` amortised lookup for a HashSet or `O(NlogM)` for a `TreeSet`.

And collating all the good ideas from the other posters:

```
buffer.view.zipWithIndex.collect { case (x,i) if !indicesToDelete.contains(i) => x }
```

To give you one pass over the data only.

Comment: You can easily optimize this by utilizing a `view` like so: `buffer.view.zipWithIndex.filter( p => !(indicesToDelete contains p._2) ).map( _._1 ).toList`. This way it'll traverse the collection just once

Answer (score 0):

```
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val indicesToDelete = List(4, 1)
val buffer = ListBuffer('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

def exclude[T](l:ListBuffer[T], indice: List[Int]) = {
  val set = indice.toSet
  l.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(ListBuffer.empty[T]){ case (c, next) =>
    if(set(next._2+1)) c else c :+ next._1
  } 

}

exclude(buffer, indicesToDelete)
```

Comment: This is O(N log M), because every lookup in `set` is O(log N)